# get value from mat-checkbox

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to get a value from a mat-checkbox but only we get boolean expression and we need a string value like this:
 `<mat-checkbox formControlName="cb2" value="success" id="cb2" name="cb2"  (change)="actualizarCheckBox()">CB2`

**so we need this 'success'**
I'm using angular 10.0.5 in win10

best regards.

Comment: You need value when checkbox checked?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way.

```
<mat-checkbox #cb2 formControlName="cb2" value="success" id="cb2" name="cb2"  (change)="actualizarCheckBox(cb2)">
```

Then, in your TS file

```
isChecked: boolean;
actualizarCheckbox(event) {
this.isChecked = !event.checked;
}
```